# Confusing Matlab Artificial Neural Toolbox script

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I'm working on a project which uses artificial neural network. I looked up at the Matlab Neural Network toolbox. I got a Generated Script from it. When looking at this script, it is confusing because for both testing and training it seems that the toolbox just uses the same data. Could you explain the reason?

The script is given below:

```
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% Train the Network

[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1};
valTargets = targets .* tr.valMask{1};
testTargets = targets .* tr.testMask{1};

trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs);
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs);
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs);
```

Also is it right to split the data set as below for training and testing?

```
trainData = inputData(:,1:213);
trainTargetData =  targetData(:,1:213);
validationData = inputData(:,214:258);
testData = inputData(:,259:end);
testTargetData = targetData(:,259:end);
validationTargetData = targetData(:,214:258);

[net,tr] = train(net,trainData,trainTargetData);

% Validation
outputs = net(validationData);
errors = gsubtract(validationTargetData,outputs);
performance = perform(net,validationTargetData,outputs);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(testData);
error = gsubtract(testTargetData,outputs);
performance = perform(net,testTargetData,outputs);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late notice, but just for future readers' sake: programming/implementation questions are much better suited to [stats.se] or [datascience.se], since this site is for social/conceptual/scientific questions about AI (as enumerated in the [help/on-topic]). I'm glad you got a good answer here, though!

Comment: The [Matlab Answers forum](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/index) has a lot of answered questions about their Neural Network toolbox too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in the generated code.
Let me explain:

In the following block, we define that 70% of the data will be used for training the network, 15% for the validation, and 15% for the testing:

```
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;
```

Then the network is trained from the inputs/targets passed as arguments. Note that here, all inputs are given at once for efficiency. The separation training/validation/testing is done inside the `net` function from the proportions passed in the `net` input argument (through the `net.divideParam.XRatio` properties).

```
% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
```

Then we test the results of the network on the data without discrimination between training/validation/testing. This performance score should be higher than the "real" performance score of the net as the performance over the training data should be higher than the one over the validation/testing data.

```
% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);  % Compute predictions from the inputs
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);  % Compare the predictions to the targets (true values)
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)  % Built-in Matlab function giving an overall performance score
```

Now that we know how the net performs overall, we can look at how it performs on the training, validation, and testing sets, respectively. The masks are created as an output of the `net` function, from the proportions given in the first block of code. The output have been already all computed when the `net` function has been called.

```
% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1}; % Apply a mask (0's and 1's to select the proper targets)
valTargets = targets .* tr.valMask{1}; % idem
testTargets = targets .* tr.testMask{1}; % idem

trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs); % Compute a score for the training data
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs); % same for the validation data
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs); % same for the test data
```

I think your code does the exact same thing but in more steps, with multiple calls to the `net` function and without using its native way of working (you define the proportions of training/validation/testing by hand for instance without making use of the `net.divideParam.Xratio` property). So it is probably not optimal from the computational point of view.